# How to persist state of plotly graph in Dash App

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have a `multi-tab`, `subtabs` dash application. I'd like to be able to save/persist the state of the components in different subtabs when switching between them. These components are `dropdown, input, graph, slider, daterange` etc.

I use the persistence property of the components which works for input, dropdown, slider but not for Graph. I'd like to persist the state of `dcc.Graph` component which renders plotly visualization.

```
dcc.Tabs(

            id="tabs",
            vertical=True,
            persistence=True,

            children=[

                 dcc.Tab(label="Tab 1", value="tab1"),
                 dcc.Tab(label="Tab 2", value="tab2",
                         children=[dcc.Tabs(id="subtabs", 
                                            persistence=True, 
                                          
                            children=[dcc.Tab(label='a', value='ab'),
                                      dcc.Tab(label='z' value='wv')
                                     
                            ],

                    )
                 ]),

            ],
            
        )
```

Is there a native solution in dash that saves the state of the app? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem when I was developing a dash app. I need to cache figures when switching between different pages. Tweaking storage_type when trying to store them works for me: https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/store

Pseudo code:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('plt','figure'),
    Input('url','pathname'), # use url to trigger callbacks
    State('plt-cached','data'),
):
def render_fig(url,plt,plt-cached):
    if url != 'cached_page': raise PreventUpdate
    if not plt: # when switching between pages, 'plt' is refreshed
        return plt-cached
    # other functions/code to render the plot in your own application
    # you might need to add other Inputs in callback

# callback functions to cache figure
@app.callback(
    Output('plt-cached','data'), # dcc.Store('plt-cached') is set to `storage_type=session`
    Input('plt','figure'),
)
def cache_fig(plt):
    return plt
```

My real application is way more complicated than the above example and the above one might doesn't work if you copy/paste it directly as I didn't even dry-run it. However, you can get the clue to solving your own problem :)